# When I Press Install Ubuntu It Won't Let ME

Tags: virtualbox

Instead of seeing this:

[image]

which I am supposed to,
I see this:

[image]

without the thing son the top check marks, although everything that it asks is okay. I have my MAC (I am using VirtualBox) plugged in a power source, I have given 10GB of free space for the Virtual Machine and I am connected to the internet. What is the problem and what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The second screenshot is for a more recent version of Ubuntu than the first screenshot. It's normal. Press Continue to continue the installation.